# Enter is required twice in my GPA Calculator

Tags: java, calculator

I barely started coding a couple weeks ago and have a project for my high school computer science class that requires me to make a GPA calculator. It's not the best code right now or the best technique to calculate GPA but it's a start (if someone could help clean it up and simplify it I would greatly appreciate you).

There's a problem with the code though. Every time a user input is required from the console they have to press enter twice. I feel like the solution is very easy but I am stuck on why this is happening.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class gpaCalc {

public static double gpa;
public static String grade = "";
public static double gpaTotal = 0;
public static double points = 0;
public static double numberOfClasses;

public static double class1points;
public static double class2points;
public static double class3points;
public static double class4points;
public static double class5points;
public static double class6points;
public static double class7points;
public static double class8points;

static Scanner letterGrade = new Scanner(System.in);
static Scanner numClasses = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Adrian's GPA calculator.");
    System.out.println("This program will calculate your weighted and unweighted GPA for this school year.");
    classesNumber();
}

public static void classesNumber() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of classes that you are enrolled in for the school year.");
    numberOfClasses = numClasses.nextDouble(); //input is stored in variable numberOfClasses

    if(numberOfClasses >= 9 || numberOfClasses < 2)
        System.out.println("Are you sure you go to ECHS?");

    //limit the number of classes from 2-8

    if (numberOfClasses <= 8 && numberOfClasses >= 2)
        System.out.println("Please enter the letter grade you have recieved in class 1 (Uppercase letters i.e. A,B,C,D,F).");
    else 
        classesNumber(); //error occurs and doesn't reset when a letter is put and not a number 
    class1();
}

public static void class1() {
    grade = letterGrade.next();   //unweighted GPA finder
    if (grade.equals("A"))
        points = 4.0;
    else if (grade.equals("B"))
            points = 3.0;
    else if (grade.equals("C"))
        points = 2.0;
    else if (grade.equals("D"))
        points = 1.0;
    else if (grade.equals("F"))
        points = 0; 
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid entry.");
        class1 ();
    }
    class1points = points;
    class2(); 
}

public static void class2() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the letter grade you have recieved in class 2 (Uppercase letters i.e. A,B,C,D,F).");
    grade = letterGrade.next();
    if (grade.equals("A"))
        points = 4.0; 
    else if (grade.equals("B"))
            points = 3.0;
    else if (grade.equals("C"))
        points = 2.0;
    else if (grade.equals("D"))
        points = 1.0;
    else if (grade.equals("F"))
        points = 0;
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid entry.");
        class2();
    }
    class2points = points;
    class3();
}   

public static void class3() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the letter grade you have recieved in class 3 (Uppercase letters i.e. A,B,C,D,F).");
    grade = letterGrade.next();
    if (grade.equals("A"))
        points = 4.0;
    else if (grade.equals("B"))
            points = 3.0;
    else if (grade.equals("C"))
        points = 2.0;
    else if (grade.equals("D"))
        points = 1.0;
    else if (grade.equals("F"))
        points = 0;
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid entry.");
        class3();
    }
    class3points = points;
    class4();
}   

public static void class4() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the letter grade you have recieved in class 4 (Uppercase letters i.e. A,B,C,D,F).");
    grade = letterGrade.next();
    if (grade.equals("A"))
        points = 4.0;
    else if (grade.equals("B"))
            points = 3.0;
    else if (grade.equals("C"))
        points = 2.0;
    else if (grade.equals("D"))
        points = 1.0;
    else if (grade.equals("F"))
        points = 0;
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid entry.");
        class4();
    }
    class4points = points;
    class5();
}   

public static void class5() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the letter grade you have recieved in class 5 (Uppercase letters i.e. A,B,C,D,F).");
    grade = letterGrade.next();
    if (grade.equals("A"))
        points = 4.0;
    else if (grade.equals("B"))
            points = 3.0;
    else if (grade.equals("C"))
        points = 2.0;
    else if (grade.equals("D"))
        points = 1.0;
    else if (grade.equals("F"))
        points = 0;
    else { 
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid entry.");
        class5();
    }
    class5points = points;
    class6();
}

public static void class6() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the letter grade you have recieved in class 6 (Uppercase letters i.e. A,B,C,D,F).");
    grade = letterGrade.next();
    if (grade.equals("A"))
        points = 4.0;
    else if (grade.equals("B"))
            points = 3.0;
    else if (grade.equals("C"))
        points = 2.0;
    else if (grade.equals("D"))
        points = 1.0;
    else if (grade.equals("F"))
        points = 0;
    else { 
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid entry.");
        class6();
    }
    class6points = points;
    class7();
}   

public static void class7() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the letter grade you have recieved in class 7 (Uppercase letters i.e. A,B,C,D,F).");
    grade = letterGrade.next();
    if (grade.equals("A"))
        points = 4.0;
    else if (grade.equals("B"))
            points = 3.0;
    else if (grade.equals("C"))
        points = 2.0;
    else if (grade.equals("D"))
        points = 1.0;
    else if (grade.equals("F"))
        points = 0;
    else { 
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid entry.");
        class7();
    }
    class7points = points;
    class8();
}

public static void class8() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the letter grade you have recieved in class 8 (Uppercase letter i.e. A,B,C,D,F).");
    grade = letterGrade.next();
    if (grade.equals("A"))
        points = 4.0;
    else if (grade.equals("B"))
            points = 3.0;
    else if (grade.equals("C"))
        points = 2.0;
    else if (grade.equals("D"))
        points = 1.0;
    else if (grade.equals("F"))
        points = 0;
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid entry.");
        class8();
    }
    class8points = points;
    calculator();
}       

public static void calculator() {
    gpaTotal = (class1points + class2points + class3points + class4points + class5points + class6points + class7points + class8points ) / numberOfClasses; 
    System.out.println("Your unwweighted GPA is: " +  gpaTotal);

}

}
```

Comment: You are using 2 scanners, you should try usin only one, as a beginning

Comment: As `System.in` is a single resource you should not have two scanners trying to read from it.

Comment: Why are you using 2 scanners. Your codes are too repetitive. Store your subjects in an array, and learn to use looping.

Comment: How would you store subjects into an array?

Comment: I don't know why i was using two scanners guys but I changed to only one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be solved by removing 1 scanner, and suggestions to your codes :

Use `array` to store subjects

> String[] mySubjects = {"sub_1", "sub_2", "sub_3", "sub_4", ..};

Use `loop` to reduce repetitive

```
for (int i = 0; i < mySubject.length; i++) {
     your_code_here;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a simplified version of your code, without need for an array.
Maybe not the best, but if you just started out, it can guide you somewhere about avoiding code repetition.

I tried to organize everything the way you did, just to help you see the code more clearly.

Maybe you can add a plus check to this code, in the classNumber() method, to avoid entering non integer values. + Split the getClassPoints() method into some parts to avoid side effects..

```
public static char grade;
public static double gpaTotal = 0;
public static int numberOfClasses;

static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Adrian's GPA calculator.");
    System.out.println("This program will calculate your weighted and unweighted GPA for this school year.");
    classesNumber();
}


public static void classesNumber() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of classes that you are enrolled in for the school year.");
    numberOfClasses = scan.nextInt(); //input is stored in variable numberOfClasses

    if(numberOfClasses >= 9 || numberOfClasses < 2)
        System.out.println("Are you sure you go to ECHS?");

    getClassPoints();
}

public static void getClassPoints () {
    //You dont need the numberOfClasses as parameter because its static.
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClasses; i++){
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Please enter the letter grade you have recieved in class " + (i + 1) +"(Uppercase letter i.e. A,B,C,D,F).");
            grade = scan.next().charAt(0);   //unweighted GPA finder
            grade = Character.toLowerCase(grade);
            if (grade == 'a'){
                gpaTotal += 4;
                break;
            }
            else if (grade == 'b'){
                gpaTotal += 3;
                break;
            }
            else if (grade == 'c'){
                gpaTotal += 2;
                break;
            }
            else if (grade == 'd'){
                gpaTotal += 1;
                break;
            }
            else if (grade == 'f'){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid entry.");;
        }
    }
    if (gpaTotal > 0){
        System.out.println("Your unwweighted GPA is: " +  (gpaTotal / numberOfClasses));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Too many F grade!");
    }
  }
}
```